# Can't get JSON to output

Tags: javascript, json, loops

First try at using JSON. I have an ajax/php function that returns a JSON object. Back on the js side, I can see the object and output it to a div. It looks fine. I can print it to the console, still looks good. But when I try to iterate over it and expose the individual values, I just get 'undefined' in my console. I can't figure out what I am missing. Sorry it if's something obvious, but I don't see it. Thanks!

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
console.log(jsonObj);   //<--looks perfect
console.log(jsonObj.length);
document.getElementById("rightsidebox").innerHTML=response; //<--looks good
for (var group in jsonObj) {
    //each of these generates 'undefined' WHY???
    //I get 4 'undefined' outputs for each group, so I know that my loop is iterating correctly
    console.log(group.id);
    console.log(group.day);
    console.log(group.time);
    console.log(group.name);  
}
```

EDIT: Here is an example of one of the JSON objects being returned by my ajax call. In this example, I only have a single object inside of the array. Of course, there will typically be multiple objects:

> [{"id":"7","day":"Thursday","time":"7:00 a.m.","name":"Sub 10:00"}]

EDIT 2: Given this array, I have to ask what the point of JSON is. I can return this array without having PHP encode it in JSON format. So, if all that comes back is just a javascript array, then what have I accomplished? Why not skip the JSON encoding in PHP and then iterate over the array? Clearly there is a reason for this, so I'm obviously missing something. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Comment: What does `console.log(jsonObj)` look like?

Comment: It looks just as it should. I can expand each group and see the set of 4 different key/value pairs.

Comment: ...and what happens if you `console.log(group)`?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj))` would be better

Comment: console.log(group) outputs '0'. Weird.

Comment: Are you sure you're not iterating an array? Then `group` would be an index.

Comment: Your going to need to show some sample json for a proper answer. (Which will probably prove Aesthete right about an array)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not sure why this works, when my original `for (var group in jsonObj)` loop doesn't, but whatever...

```
for (var i=0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
    console.log(jsonObj[i].id);
    console.log(jsonObj[i].day);
    console.log(jsonObj[i].time);
    console.log(jsonObj[i].name);
}
```

Comment: -1? Why? Can't stand these drive-by down votes with no explanation.

Comment: -1, because you only have an array with one element. The loop is pointless, you could just use `jsonObj[0]`.

Comment: Only in this example. I was trying to keep it simple. As I explained above, in a live situation, I have multiple objects.

Comment: I retain my downvote, as your post is more of a question than an answer. You found a why to get it to work, but say that you don't know why. The reason, btw, is that you have an array, and for...in loops are not good at looping through arrays. They loop through the `keys` not the `values` so you would still need to do `jsonObj[group]` to access the value.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following:

```
var myJson = '{"groupA": {"id": 123, "name": "foo"}}';
var myObj = JSON.parse(myJson);
for (var i in myObj) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(i.id);
    console.log(myObj[i].id);
}
```

The expected output here is:

```
myGroup
undefined
123
```

This is because you loop is just assigning the 'key' of your object to the value `i`. If you were to iterate an *array*, instead of an object, you'd get *indices* instead of strings.

In the example JSON you've given, you have an *array* with *one object in it*. If you intend to have multiple objects in your array, something like this would be better:

```
for (var group in jsonObj) {
  var thisGroup = jsonObj[group];
  thisGroup.id; // Etc etc..
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that this is right, however. Yes, I have one object in my array. But that's the point of the `for (var group in jsonObj)` loop - to iterate over each object. In the code you suggest, you loop over the array, then you loop over each element in the object, then you refer to an index inside of the object, then you refer to the key inside the index??? When I do this, I still get 'undefined' as my output, only this time I get lots of them. If this is right, then I don't see the point of JSON at all. It has to be simpler than this. Am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the follow up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct jsonObj, and you say that you do, you can use formatting to output the object in an easy to read form.  You don't have to loop through it.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj, null, 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But what does this accomplish? As I see it, this function converts a JSON object into a string. Why would I want to do that? And how does that allow me to not have to loop through it?